# join query in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables 1. user 2. shortlist

now m getting user details in which I also want details like user is shortlisted by me or not.  how can I get these data using join.
common fields : user.id == Shortlisted or user.id = ShortlistedBy

Currently I am getting only user data by this query

```
$users = DB::table('user')

         ->select('user.Name','user.Age','user.FatherGotra','user.Profession','user.City','user.State','user.AreYouManglik','user.DOB','user.ProfilePic','user.id')

                        ->where('ShowProfileOnMatrimony','YES')
                        ->where('Mobile','!=',$request->Mobile)
                        ->where('isVerified',1)
                        ->orderBy('user.id','DESC')
                        ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what columns you want to join on? Your question seems a bit vague

Comment: actually i want to get data when m getting user detail that user is shortlisted by me or not. there are two colums which we can join user.id == Shortlisted or user.id = ShortlistedBy but m confused becoz m new to php. how can i do that.

Comment: See my answer, let me know if it's not what you were expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$users = DB::table('user')->select('user.Name','user.Age','user.FatherGotra','user.Profession','user.City','user.State','user.AreYouManglik','user.DOB','user.ProfilePic','user.id','shortlist.isShortlisted as isshortlist')
                    ->leftJoin('shortlist', 'user.id', 'Shortlisted')
                    ->leftJoin('shortlist as ShortlistedBy', 'user.id', 'shortlist.ShortlistedBy')
                    ->where('ShowProfileOnMatrimony','YES')
                    ->where('Mobile','!=',$request->Mobile)
                    ->where('isVerified',1)
                    ->orderBy('user.id','DESC')
                    ->paginate(5);
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins

Comment: no record found. I want if user not shortlisted by me a key shows like: isUserShortListed : True/False

Comment: Sorry, should work with a left join. Please see answer

Comment: here i confused with .     ->leftJoin('Shortlisted', 'user.id', 'Shortlisted')
                    ->leftJoin('Shortlisted as ShortlistedBy', 'user.id', 'Shortlisted.ShortlistedBy').     my second table is 'shortlist' and coloum name is shortlisted. I can't join this but when i put my table name by replace ->leftjoin('shortlist'.... i get data but there is nothing like is shortlisted or not. it showing only userdetail

Comment: Oh.. You didn't mention that your table was called `shortlist`. Check answer now. Without knowing the exact column names and table names it's going to be hard for me to get the correct answer. Maybe edit your question with relevant data or edit my answer with correct table and column names?

Comment: at the top i mention i have two tables 1.user 2. shortlist

Comment: i edit you query according to table and i get my data. :) thanks.

Comment: ya that what i want. but i also add one thing in select which is 'shortlist.isShortlisted as isshortlist'. Thanks buddy.

Comment: No worries, please can you make sure to edit my answer to the working query to help people in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB::table('shortlist')
    ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'shortlist.user_id')
    ->select('shortlist.*', 'user.name as user_name')
    ->where('ShowProfileOnMatrimony','YES')
    ->where('Mobile','!=',$request->Mobile)
    ->where('isVerified',1)
    ->paginate(8);
```

Comment: make changes according to your need

Comment: here * choose all table of shortlist and in user table we pick only the content we want you can choose more as per your need